# Aparecer div consoante condição

Tags: php, div

Boa tarde

No final de uma encomenda eu quero que apareça uma div consoante o metodo de pagamento, talvez identificar pelo nome do método de pagamento. A div em questão é esta

```html
<div>
<h2>
 <a href="javascript:submitPaymentByPopUp('<?php echo $viewData["order_number"];?>','<?php echo $viewData['displayTotalInPaymentCurrency'];?>','','site',500,600);">Fazer pagamento</a></h2>
 </div>
```

o código todo da página é este:

```html
<?php
defined ('_JEXEC') or die();

?>
<div class="post_payment_payment_name" style="width: 100%">
 <span class="post_payment_payment_name_title"><?php echo vmText::_ ('VMPAYMENT_STANDARD_PAYMENT_INFO'); ?> </span>
 <?php echo  $viewData["payment_name"]; ?>
</div>

  <div>
<h2>
 <a href="javascript:submitPaymentByPopUp('<?php echo $viewData["order_number"];?>','<?php echo $viewData['displayTotalInPaymentCurrency'];?>','','site',500,600);">Fazer pagamento</a></h2>
 </div>


<div class="post_payment_order_number" style="width: 100%">
 <span class="post_payment_order_number_title"><?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDER_NUMBER'); ?> </span>
 <?php echo  $viewData["order_number"]; ?>
</div>

<div class="post_payment_order_total" style="width: 100%">
 <span class="post_payment_order_total_title"><?php echo vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDER_PRINT_TOTAL'); ?> </span>
 <?php echo  $viewData['displayTotalInPaymentCurrency']; ?>
</div>
<a class="vm-button-correct" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=orders&layout=details&order_number='.$viewData["order_number"].'&order_pass='.$viewData["order_pass"], false)?>"><?php echo vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDER_VIEW_ORDER'); ?></a>
```

A minha questão é, conforme o nome do meio de pagamento se dá para esconder a div onde é chamado o pop up, ou seja, só quero que aparece para um método de pagamento.

Comment: Seja mais claro na descrição do problema, da maneira como se encontra fica difícil entender o que estás a fazer e qual o resultado que desejas obter.

Comment: A minha questão é, conforme o nome do meio de pagamento se dá para esconder a div onde é chamado o pop up, ou seja, só quero que apareça para um método de pagamento.

Comment: Veja se a resposta que dei soluciona o teu problema, @alfredo.

Comment: Não @Marcelo de Andrade, coloquei o código mas a página apresenta o erro HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 0):

Faça a verificação do meio de pagamento utilizando o [`if`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.if.php):

```
<?php if ($viewData["payment_name"] == 'PayPal'): ?>
    <a href="javascript:submitPaymentByPopUp('<?=$viewData["order_number"];?>','<?=$viewData['displayTotalInPaymentCurrency'];?>','','site',500,600);">Fazer pagamento</a></h2>
<?php end if; ?>
```

**Dica**:

Você pode utilizar a short tag `<?= ?>` para exibir texto, no lugar da tag completa `<?php echo ... ?>`

Comment: Não @Marcelo de Andrade, coloquei o código mas a página apresenta o erro HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: Habilite as mensagens de erro do `PHP` para verificar o que está ocorrendo. `Erro 500` é genérico demais para saber o que houve.